# mysqld.sock missing in tmp folder

Tags: mysql

i am a beginner learning RoR (version 3.1.1). i wanted to use mysql for database.
i created a  new rails project using the code `rails new hello -d mysql`,and created a database table.
checked the database.yml file in the config folder and added the password for the database access.
But when i try to run `rake db:migrate` i get the following error :

`rake aborted!
syntax error on line 18, col 2:   'socket: /tmp/mysqld.sock'`

checked the tmp folder using the terminal but there was no `mysqld.sock` file.

how do i configure for mysql?

I am using it on MAC OS X 10.6.8

Answer (score 1):

Check you /etc/my.cnf (not sure where it is on windows) and look for the "socket" config line - this will tell you were the mysql unix local socket is.

```
grep sock /etc/my.cnf 
socket          = /tmp/mysql.sock
```

Comment: I dont see any my.cnf in the etc folder. Navigates using terminal and used `ls -la` to check the folder contents.

Comment: The you may be using default compiled values. How did you install mysql?

Comment: i downloaded and installed mysql from here [link] (http://mysql.phphosts.org/Downloads/MySQL-5.1/mysql-5.1.59-osx10.6-x86_64.dmg) . it had the mysql package,the startup option and preference pane settings.

Comment: Ok - my biggest worry here is that it is not from a Linux distro or from mysql. I personally would not trust this site even though it looks like mysql's site. Although there are 1000's of open source sites that are trying to help and I probably dont know it. Just checking DMG is an apple thing which I am unfamiliar with. Hopefully it installed some docs and you should be able to locate where apple default install the config

Comment: Thanks for trying. will search for any documents available .

Comment: I know there is either a mysql system variable or command line option to tell you - but for the life of me I cannot remember what it is and I cant find it :-(

Answer (score 1):

as a head up try using `127.0.0.1` instead `localhost`

this will make connect the client using TCP instead sockets.

Comment: Not true locahost can be configured as many things eg: ping localhost
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.027 ms

Comment: database doesn't depend on the TCP connection right? I am having trouble configuring the database itself.

Comment: @AdrianCornish ... remove `127.0.0.1 localhost` form your `/etc/hosts` file and what you did wont work. `localhost` is just an alias to 127.0.0.1

Comment: @Gabriel Sosa - and why would you do something so stupid. It does not make mysql connect via a unix socket over a tcp socket. All you are doing is confusing the OP with stuff that is not relevant - we could change it to IPv6 address or maybe to 127.123.124.15 - but it doesnt help the OP configure Rails to find the unix socket does it?

Comment: Still mysql will connect using TCP when given `127.0.0.1` and using the socket when given `localhost`, so it would help the OP.

Comment: @AdrianCornish I won't do it. I'm just proving that you said is a specific case of what I said. `localhost` is an alias of `127.0.0.1` and it is relevant as @AndreKR said.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the `mysqld.sock` file is in `/var/run/mysqld/`.

You could simply create a symlink:

`ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysqld.sock`

Comment: No it is not - it depends on your mysql install/distro etc - show me that location on a windows box!

Comment: He said he "checked the tmp folder using the terminal" so it's most probably not a windows box. However +1 for your more generic answer.

Comment: agree with you AndreKR - was trying to make the point you picked up on though. (3 edits later because its removing user names)

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys. i tried using ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysqld.sock but it didnt work. i am running it on a mac